# Spring boot data JPA with hibernate mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm working in `Spring Boot` project connect with `JPA`. I'm stuck in the mapping `many-to-many` relationship between `users` and `roles`. I'm using persistence tool to generate java class according to schema table.

**Sql script for table USERS:**

```
CREATE TABLE "MPOSML"."USERS" 
   (    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "BRANCH_ID" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
    "GROUP_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "ENABLED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATE_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "PREFERED_LOCALE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'en', 
    "PREFERED_THEME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "FAILED_ATTEMPTS" NUMBER(3,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "CLIENT_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "TEL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE), 
    "C_SMS" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "C_IDEVICE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "C_WEB" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "C_ANDROID" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) DEFAULT 'false', 
    "DEVICE_CODE" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) DEFAULT 'WEB', 
    "ISAUTHORIZE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_ENABLED_CHECK" CHECK ("ENABLED" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_GROUP_ID_CHECK" CHECK ("GROUP_ID" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_PASSWORD_CHECK" CHECK ("PASSWORD" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "USERS_USER_NAME_CHECK" CHECK ("USER_NAME" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_USERS" PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID", "CLIENT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

**sql for table ROLES**

```
CREATE TABLE "MPOSML"."ROLES" 
   (    "ROLE_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "ROLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "ENABLED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "ROLE_GROUP" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_ENABLED_CHECK" CHECK ("ENABLED" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_ROLE_NAME_CHECK" CHECK ("ROLE_NAME" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE NOVALIDATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "ROLES_UNIQUE_KEY" UNIQUE ("ROLE_NAME")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_ROLES" PRIMARY KEY ("ROLE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

**SQL for table USERS_ROLES**

```
CREATE TABLE "MPOSML"."USERS_ROLES" 
   (    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "ROLE_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "SELECTED" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "VERSION_NUMBER" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "CLIENT_ID" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "USERSROLES_PRIMARY_KEY" PRIMARY KEY ("CLIENT_ID", "USER_ID", "ROLE_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_USERSROLES_ROLE_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ROLE_ID")
      REFERENCES "MPOSML"."ROLES" ("ROLE_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE NOVALIDATE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MPOS" ;
```

Then, after generate java class, it contains 3 files: Roles, Users and UsersPK
**Class UsersPK**

```
public class UsersPK implements Serializable {
    private String userId;
    private String clientId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @Id
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID")
    @Id
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
}
```

**Class Users**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UsersPK.class)
public class Users {
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String clientId;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Roles> roles;
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    public Set<Roles> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Roles> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
   //getter and setter
}
```

**Class Roles**

```
@Entity
public class Roles {
    private String roleId;
    private String roleName;
    private String enabled;
    private String createdBy;
    private Time createdOn;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Time modifiedOn;
    private Long versionNumber;
    private String roleGroup;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users;

//getter & setter
}
```

After `generate java class`, I added `many-to-many relationship` for `2 classes Users and Roles`. Then, when I run project, the console log shows:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(roles)]
```

I made a research in some articles and saw that their mapping same as mine, don't know what happen with this one.

Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Remove `mappedBy` you do either `mappedBy` or a join table but not both.

Comment: Hi, just try to remove mappedBy and keep join table, but result still same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your `@JoinTable` should be on the field NOT the getter. also annotations should be either on get/set methods or fields not both.